# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/cdk/tree' '@angular/material/tree'

Tags: angular, typescript, treeview, angular-material

I'm using Angular 5 and trying to achieve a tree view like this with a table like display.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hhkrr1?file=main.ts

when I try to import

import {NestedTreeControl} from '@angular/cdk/tree';
import {MatTreeNestedDataSource} from '@angular/material/tree';

I'm getting error

ERROR in ./src/app/app.module.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve
'@angular/cdk/tree' in 'XXX'
ERROR in ./src/app/AgileBOM/agile-bom.tabs.component.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve
'@angular/cdk/tree' in 'XXX'
ERROR in ./src/app/AgileBOM/agile-bom.tabs.component.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve
'@angular/material/tree' in 'XXX'

I tried "npm install" - Didn't work also tried to install angular material & cdk but in vain.

What could be the issue

Comment: It seems like `@angular/cdk/tree`(introduced from @angular/material 6+ version) package is missing, the reason could be you have to download `@angular/material` & `@angular/cdk` latest version (6.x.x)

Comment: I tried installing the latest, then I'm getting error for existing material module..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Tree component is new in Angular Material 6 which requires Angular 6. You would need to upgrade your application's various Angular dependencies from 5.x in order to use the Tree component.